# azure iothub direct method not working as expected

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

i was able to open a listener on iothub messages (messages from cloud to deivce) but i am unable to subscribe to direct method . I am trying to use mqtt support , not the iothub library

I have followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods#mqtt
but there must be a small detail that i haven't managed to do correctly yet

this is my code (python)

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt
import ssl
import token_generator #a script that exports the token , it is working fine for device messages

path_to_root_cert = "cert.cer"
device_id = "mydevice_id "
endpoint ="myiot_hub_name.azure-devices.net/devices/mydevice_id "
policyKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
sas_token =  token_generator.generate_sas_token(endpoint ,policyKey ,None)
iot_hub_name = "myiot_hub_name"

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  print ("Device connected with result code: " + str(rc))
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
  print ("Device disconnected with result code: " + str(rc))
def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
  print ("Device sent message")
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Message received at: " + msg.topic+" with payload: "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client(client_id=device_id, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.on_message = on_message

client.username_pw_set(username=iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net/" + device_id, password=sas_token)

client.tls_set(ca_certs=path_to_root_cert, certfile=None, keyfile=None, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, ciphers=None)
client.tls_insecure_set(False)

client.connect(iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net", port=8883 )

client.subscribe("iothub/methods/POST/")

client.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

the client should be subscribed on the topic:

```
$iothub/methods/POST/#
```

the following are others topics for subscribing:

```
$iothub/twin/res/#
$iothub/twin/PATCH/properties/desired/#
devices/{myDeviceId}/messages/devicebound/#
devices/{myDeviceId}/modules/{myModuleId}/messages/devicebound/#
```

and for device streams (currently in the preview)

```
$iothub/streams/POST/#
```

Comment: I have also tried to change to client.subscribe("$iothub/methods/POST/#") with regretably no success so far , i think the error is somewhere else

Comment: what is the error code from the invoker. If your device is connected and not subscribed for methods, than the error message is: "Timed out waiting for device to subscribe.", you can test it with a Device Explorer tool.

Comment: the error that appears when uising the mqtt method  is "Timed out waiting for the device to connect"

Comment: but it works fine with python iothub package , but i need it to run on mqtt

Comment: it looks like your device is not connected to the Azure IoT Hub. Try to use a tool for instance: MQTTBox client or MQTT.fx client for test purposes such as the connection, subscribing, publishing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I faced also such a problem. After spending some time I found out that the actual problem is in the python example.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device) the username should be
`{iothubhostname}/{device_id}/?api-version=2018-06-30` but in the example the version is missing. As result if you try to subscribe to any topic starting from `$iothub` it doesn't work.

After fixing the username everything works fine for me.